# When using /sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/ <ContentDocument IDs> , can we rename the zip folder document?

Tags: apex, visualforce, fields, url, urlhacking

I have used the Custom button (**/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/** ) to download all the files realed to an object. The Zip folder always has a name “downloaded-content”. So I need to change this name to “file.zip”.

**Is it possible to rename the Zip folder?**